# Loading JS dynamically from another JS (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, load, external

I'd like to know if I can load an external JS dynamically based on some condition, for example:

```
$(window).load(function () {
   if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version=="6.0") {
     // load ie.js
     // do stuff using ie.js
   }
});
```

Comment: The use of $.browser.msie like that is deprecated in jQuery 1.3+.

Comment: @cletus: no it isn't. `jQuery.browser`, although no longer used by jQuery internally, is available to user scripts for the indefinite future: http://docs.jquery.com/Utilities/jQuery.browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JQuery's GetScript](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript) should do it.

```
$.getScript("yourscirpt.js", function() {
    alert('Load Complete');
});
```

Comment: So if the above function is in /dir/one.js, yourscript.js should be in the same dir?

Comment: The first argument is a URL, not a path. `$.getScript()` is really making an AJAX call.

Answer (score 3):

If not using jquery, use this to include js

```
document.writeln('<script type="text/javascript" src="your.js"></script>');
```

Comment: could you also use this notation?
    <script type="text/javascript" src="your.js"/>
so that you close the script tag and dont have to leave the value empty

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.getScript(url,callback)`; it loads the script, and executes it.